# How do you describe the direct accessing of the underlying data member of a std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

I've seen implementations of `std::array` where all members are `public`. This, however, does **not** mean that the underlying array (or whatever type of data member there is) should be directly accessed by referring to its name. I know that the standard way of accessing the said member is through `std::array::data()`.

Is there a specification from the ISO C++ standard that describes the attempt of directly accessing the underlying data member by referring to its name?

Let's assume that the underlying `public` data member is a fixed size array and its name is `_data`.

```cpp
std::array<char, 10> a{};
a._data[0] = 'A';
```

How does the ISO C++ standard describe the second statement? Is it undefined behavior? Unspecified?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if accessing the public member directly is illegal?

Comment: It's probably implementation-defined if the underlaying array is public, and the name of it. Why would you depend on something that's in no way portable?

Comment: What's not direct about `.data()`? You can do `&arr[0];` if that's better in your opinion.

Comment: @Kaldrr It must be public, because `std::array` relies on aggregate initialization and has no (user-declared) constructors.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard does not define under which member name `std::array` stores the array. It does not say if there shall be a member named `_arr` or `_data` or whatever. It specifies some functions like `data` and `operator[]` and `at` to access the data. So if you want to write code that follows the C++ standard, then you are bound to the specified functions. If you have one implementation of the STL and see that there `std::array` has a public member `arr` you can use it. But you will have code that is not portable and will not work with other implementations of the STL. Even worse: if the author of your STL does not guarantee that `std::array` will not change, he can in a future update change the name of the member. The STL will still be C++ standard compliant but your code will not compile anymore.

To make it short: you should not directly use the data member, you should access it through the C++ standardized functions. Relying on a given member name is implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: [@Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023911/werner-henze)
I do know that the name of the data member is implementation defined and that no one should ever attempt to directly refer to it. If, for whatever reason, someone attempted to do it, how would the standard describe that attempt? Is it undefined behavior? Unspecified?

Comment: @AJTan Implementation defined.

Comment: The standard does talk about how `std::array` should store its data though. At least continuous.

Comment: @HattedRooster I know that was not very precise. I edited my answer.