# std::array's data member is public in a standard library implementation. Why?

Tags: c++, std

I was trying to study standard library implementation of the containers that are part of the C++ standard library. I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 on my machine and I could go to the header file definition of `std::array` class.

While I reached the end of the class definition of `std::array` class, I noticed that the data member is not declared private and above it were all the public member functions, so that make the data member public as well.

So to test it, I tried to access it in my `std::array` object defined in `main()` and to my surprise I could access it and it printed the proper value in the output too!

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    std::array<int, 5> staticArray{0,1,2,3,4};
    std::cout << staticArray._Elems[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Is this allowed?! Anybody can corrupt the data, right?

Comment: It's implementation-dependent. This code is [not portable](https://godbolt.org/z/onc49cxxK). Use the interface defined by the standard library. There is zero reason not to.

Comment: It doesn't provide any way to "corrupt" the data that normal access through `[]` or `data()`would not.

Comment: @paddy the `data` member is not implementation defined, it's part of the standard interface.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data

Comment: @MarkRansom I think here it's more about the member name of the thing that `data()` returns - in VC++ it's apparently `_Elems`, in Clang it's `__elems_`, in GCC it's `_M_elems_`

Comment: @MarkRansom The question is about the member named `_Elems` being public. I can only assume it's like that to reduce stress on the compiler when handling `std::get` etc.

Comment: @paddy sorry, I didn't read the question closely enough.  The general rule in C++ is that variables starting with `_` are meant for compiler use only.  I have no idea why they didn't make it private.

Comment: That's a rule in C, but murkier in C++ where it doesn't apply to everything. When it comes to naming members, underscore prefixes are not reserved. But yeah, when one sees that in a standard library implementation, one generally knows not to touch them.

Comment: Dupe: [How do you describe the direct accessing of the underlying data member of a std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504609/how-do-you-describe-the-direct-accessing-of-the-underlying-data-member-of-a-std)

Comment: @AnoopRana The link isn't asking why it's public, it's asking if said access is legal. These are different questions.

Comment: @PasserBy Both questions are same. In particular, the dupe's title asks: [How do you describe the direct accessing of the underlying data member of a std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504609/how-do-you-describe-the-direct-accessing-of-the-underlying-data-member-of-a-std)

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the compiler and the standard library implementation. You are not supposed to use them except if the language standard(s), the compiler or the standard library document them as a public interface. In theory you could access all kinds of standard library internals to get around the defined interfaces, but that is going to be completely non-portable and subject to spontaneous breakage when the developers decide to change something, as well as undefined behavior per standard.

Comment: @AnoopRana I just said why they're not. You might want to rebut that. That the answer happens to partially overlap doesn't make the question the same.

Comment: @PasserBy I am not saying that they're same because the answer overlap. Instead they're same because the intent of the questions is same, just worded little differently. Additionally, note that in this question OP also says: *"Anybody can corrupt the data,"*

Comment: @AnoopRana except the other one doesn't actually answer why it's public. The  'dupe' implies it's circumstance, whereas the answer to this one actually gives a C++ standard-based reasoning.

Comment: @wkl The point is a) the questions have the same meaning b) and this answer can be posted there.

Comment: @AnoopRana mpark's answer specifically would stand out like a sore thumb because the link doesn't ask about the _why_. So no, I don't think so.

Comment: @PasserBy The dupe clearly ask "how `a._data[0] = 'A';` is described by the C++ standard".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is required that `std::array` have a public member to satisfy the requirement that `std::array` be an aggregate.

> An array is an aggregate that can be list-initialized with up to N elements whose types are convertible to T.
>
> https://eel.is/c++draft/array#overview-2

It doesn't however specify what the public member should be named, since the only requirement is that it is an aggregate that can be list-initialized.

`_Elems` won't necessarily be compatible with other standard library implementations.

With respect to your concern of anyone being able to corrupt the data, anyone can already do that via any of the mutable accessors: `data()`, `operator[]`, etc

Comment: Note that because `_Elems` begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, the standard does not allow you to use the name (they are reserved for the implementation "for any use"). Therefore, if your program uses such an identifier, even if you didn't *define* it, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Can you elaborate what exactly does being 'aggregate' mean? Does this apply to other container classes too?

Comment: @ZoomIn not my answer, but check out [aggregates on cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Explanation). And no, most std containers aren't aggregates and would not pass `std::is_aggregate`.

Answer (score -1):

@mpark has got it exactly right. (Hi, Michael!)

```
template <typename T, size_t SZ>
struct Arr1 {
public:
    T elems[SZ];
};
    
template <typename T, size_t SZ>
struct Arr2 {
private:
    T elems[SZ];
};

int main () {
    static_assert (std::is_aggregate<Arr1<int, 4>>::value, ""); // OK
    static_assert (std::is_aggregate<Arr2<int, 4>>::value, ""); // fails
}
```

Comment: Hi Marshall! 

Comment: Didn't vote on this, but I'd be inclined for @mpark to include this code example as an extension to their existing answer and credit you for providing it. That's more appropriate than a code-only answer referencing an existing answer.